# Run a program without Try/Catch block

Tags: java, try-catch

I'm making a sort of chat program in Java. Specifically, if I ask "can you open chrome?", the program will reply with "yes..." and then opens Google Chrome (Windows).

I have created the path to the Chrome as a string:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime()
String file="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\Chrome.exe";
```

I try to call the String, but says to either "Surround Statement with try/catch" or "Surround block with try/catch". Or the "Add throws clause to the "java.io.IOException" ".

```
myVocab.addPhrase("Can you open Chrome?", "Yes, one moment..." + rt.exec(file));
```

Whenever I do either of these, Chrome just opens automatically.

I'm somewhat new to Java so please tell me if there's an easier way to do this, or if I'm doing this completely wrong.

Comment: Just a heads up, some people will not have that path you've specified to launch Chrome. (i.e. people on Mac)

Comment: So when you reference `addPhrase`, does that add the question it's looking for and the answer it will give?

Comment: Yes, it looks for the "Can you open Chrome" and replies with "Yes, one moment."

Answer (score 1):

Some java functions need to be implemented with the try catch statements because it is possible to get an exception inside that function. An exception is defined as "An exception is an event, which occurs during the execution of a program, that disrupts the normal flow of the program's instructions" [more info](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html)

So, to manage an exception, for your case, you could:

try {   code1   } catch (ExceptionType name) {  code2   } 
where ExceptionType should correspond to the possible error type your code1 could give you. 
Ex: 
`try {  //code to open google   } catch (InterruptedException e) {  e.printStackTrace();    }`
e.printStackTrace(); will print error details